# Why did this character leave the Lethal Weapon tv series?

Tags: character, production, casting, lethal-weapon-tv

Why was the character

> Martin Riggs

killed off the [*Lethal Weapon*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5164196/) tv series after only 2 seasons?

It seemed sudden and rushed and given the importance of the character to the movie franchise it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clayne Crawford, actor, who played Martin Riggs on the Fox drama, was officially removed from the series after previously being reprimanded twice for his on-set behaviour.

Reasons behind his reprimand is taken from [digitalspy](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/news/a855558/lethal-weapon-tv-series-cast-clayne-crawford-series-2-reprimanded-twice/)

> Lethal Weapon's Clayne Crawford has addressed rumours regarding his
>   on-set behaviour, confirming that he was "reprimanded twice" during
>   the series' second season.
>
> In a lengthy statement posted to Instagram, Crawford explained the
>   reasons behind his disciplinary action and apologised to those who
>   felt "less than comfortable on our set".
>
> "The first reprimand was because I reacted with anger over working
>   conditions that did not feel safe or conducive to good work under the
>   leadership of a guest director and assistant director who, in turn,
>   were angry at my response," he wrote.
>
> "I met with Human Resources, I apologized for my part of the conflict,
>   and I completed studio-appointed therapy."
>   Crawford went on to share the reason for "the second reprimand", which
>   took place during an episode that he was directing.
>
> "An actor on set felt unsafe because of a piece of shrapnel from an
>   effect hit him. It was an unfortunate event that happened in spite of
>   all safety precautions and procedures being followed," the actor
>   wrote, before adding: "I take responsibility for the incident".
>
> Responding directly to reports that season three of the Fox series was
>   in jeopardy, Crawford said: "I absolutely love, respect and care for
>   my crew and cast, and would never intentionally jeopardize so many
>   jobs.
>
> "Moreover, I love the process of making film and television. I
>   appreciate and respect the work of everyone invovled. It takes a
>   village."

From different [digitalspy article](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/feature/a858266/lethal-weapon-season-3-clayne-crawford-damon-wayans/),

> Reports emerged that Lethal Weapon's renewal status was up in the air
>   after it was alleged that Clayne Crawford had been disciplined after
>   multiple complaints about his behaviour on set.
>
> It was further reported that a recasting was being explored for future
>   seasons as cast and crew were said to feel uncomfortable being on set
>   with him.

He had a breakdowns with his co star Damon Waynas and the crew multiple times and he had became a very hard man to work with. So fox had to fire him.

From [digitalspy](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/news/a857045/lethal-weapon-clayne-crawford-fired-replaced-seann-william-scott/)

> Crawford had been reported that had a breakdowns with his co star
>   Damon Waynas and the crew
>   multiple times and he had became a very hard man to work with. So fox
>   first looked somebody to replace him as Riggs in the drama and later
>   had a workaround that Riggs should be stay dead and they brings up a
>   new character who is played by Sean William Scott in from the third
>   season.
>
> Taking to Instagram on Sunday (May 13), Clayne posted a picture of
>   himself look downcast next to a caption congratulating the remaining
>   Lethal Weapon cast and crew on being renewed for a third season and
>   wishing them luck going forward.
>
> "To my cast and crew - congratulations on season three," he said.
>
> "To the fans - thank you for the overwhelming support and love. Riggs
>   was a dream role and the experience will live with me forever.
>
> "My heart is full. Good luck next season!!"

Fox first looked somebody to replace him as Riggs in the drama and later had a workaround that Riggs should be stay dead and they brings up a new character who is played by Sean William Scott in from the third season.

From [digitalspy](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/news/a857045/lethal-weapon-clayne-crawford-fired-replaced-seann-william-scott/)

> Following confirmation this weekend that the show had been
>   renewed for a third season, Fox revealed that American Pie and Role
>   Models star Seann William Scott will replace Clayne, with speculation
>   that his character will be the brother of Clayne's Martin Riggs.

Crawford has issued an apology on instagram. you can see a screenshot [here](http://digitalspyuk.cdnds.net/18/22/768x789/gallery-1527696431-c.jpg)

You can read more about that from below links,

[tvline](https://tvline.com/2018/05/08/clayne-crawford-leaving-lethal-weapon-season-3-controversy-recast/)

[bustle](https://www.bustle.com/p/is-clayne-crawford-returning-to-lethal-weapon-he-made-a-very-public-exit-12013071)

[vulture](http://www.vulture.com/2018/09/lethal-weapon-season-3-premiere-clayne-crawford.html)

[variety](https://variety.com/2018/tv/news/lethal-weapon-clash-shakeup-firing-video-1202822990/)